# How to show that $T(n) = T(n-1) + \Theta(n)$ is in $\Omega(n^2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

In the class we have been shown the way to prove that 
$T(n) = T(n-1) + \Theta(n)$ is in $O(n^2)$

$$
\begin{align}
T(n)&\le T(n-1) +cn &\\
    &\le c(n-1)^2+cn &\\
    &=cn^2-2cn+c+cn\\
    &=cn^2-cn+c\\
    &=c(n^2-n+1)\le cn^2 &\
\end{align}
$$

Then we were said that it is easy to see that $T(n) = T(n-1) + \Theta(n)$ is in $\Omega(n^2)$. But, I do not understand how to "see" this really.
As I understand we need to show that

$$
T(n-1) + \Theta(n)\ge cn^2
$$
Right? I have no idea how to do that. Need help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how they got the first inequality?

Comment: @science not exactly...

Comment: So how can you prove the other case?

Comment: @science well, I guess we just assumed $T(n) <= O(n^2)$ and this we substituted T(n-1) with squared expression. That is what I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be the lower bound so that your $\Theta (n)$ is greater than or equal to $cn$. Then you have

$$T(n) \geq T(1) + c\sum_{j=1}^n j = T(1) + cn(n+1)/2 = \Omega(n^2)$$

The only tricky thing there is knowing the formula for $\sum_{j=1}^n j$. But that's a classical result, you can look up sum of consecutive integers for example.

Comment: I did not really understand anything :( could you give more detailed explanation please

Comment: @UserMoon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score -1):

The following definition is useful for your purpose  $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ means that

$$ c_1\, g(n) \leq  f(n) \leq c_2 \,g(n) $$

for some positive $k_1,k_2$.

Comment: We need to prove that recurrence is in Theta and thus we should show bigO and Omega

Comment: The title says in $\Omega$!